# Derivation of integral approximation to $\frac{1}{k}\sum_{0 \le j \le k}(\frac{j}{k})^{n}$

Tags: calculus, summation

I found the following integral approximation in a textbook.

$$\frac{1}{k}\sum_{0 \le j \le k}(\frac{j}{k})^{n} \approx \int_0^1x^{n} \mathrm dx = \frac{1}{n+1}$$

for large $k$. What is the derivation for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called a [Riemann Sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum). It can be viewed as drawing rectangles of height $\left(\frac{j}{k}\right)^n$ for $x = \frac{j}{k}$ in the interval $[0, 1]$; this will closely approximate the area under the curve $y = x^n$.

Comment: Why is the interval $[0, 1]$ chosen as the limits of integration?

Comment: Because $0 \le \frac{j}{k} \le 1$ for such choices of $j$. Try drawing the rectangles; also, I'd guess that you probably meant to have the sum over $0 \le j < k$.

Comment: Is this what you meant? Let $x = \frac{j}{k}$. Then $\frac{1}{k}\sum_{0 \le \frac{j}{k} \le 1} (\frac{j}{k})^n = \sum_{0 \le x \le 1} x^n \approx \int_{0}^{1} x^n \mathrm dx = \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1} \mid_0^1 = \frac{1}{n+1}$
As for $0 \le j \lt k$, the book has $0 \le j \le k$. Any reason why the difference would matter here?